# Does an Azure Virtual machine image maintain SSL configuration?

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-virtual-machine

I have a VM (IIS server) using a SSL certificate and also serves as a reverse proxy.
I plan on using the image from the VM to deploy a virtual machine scale set (with all the IIS and SSL config in place), will this work?

Answer (score 0):

Sysprep, the process which generalizes an image to prepare it for use in a VMSS makes private keys inaccessible on clones, effectively removing the certificates. See: https://serverfault.com/questions/755057/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-sysprep-from-destroying-your-iis-installation

To re-inject your certificates into your image after generalization, you can use a tool such as the Custom Script Extension to reinstall the certs. For example: https://medium.com/charot/custom-script-extention-on-azure-vmss-e010a8c87904